# Why does the type change?

Tags: angular

When i execute

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Car } from '../_models/car';
@Injectable()
export class UserCarsService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getAll(params : any =  {params:{all:true}}) {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>('/api/user-cars', params);
}
```

}

`getAll()` returns `<HttpEvent<Car[]>>` type

but if i change this function to

`getAll(params ={}) {
        return this.http.get<Car[]>('/api/user-cars', params);
    }`

function will return Observable type.
why this happens and how to fix it

error is caused in this function which resolves data before route:

```
`resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.service.getAll({
        params : {
            id : Number(route['_urlSegment']['segments'][1]['path'])
        }
    );
    }`
```

Comment: what does the function look like when it returns <HttpEvent<Car[]>> ?

Comment: You need to subscribe to that Observable.

Comment: HttpClient always returns a observable

Comment: yes it always retrurns Observable,but I get an error at compilation

Comment: Maybe show the actual error you at getting, and the corresponding line of code?